# Two arrays to be evaluated element by element in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Sorry for unclear title, however, I hope the body describes my problem clearly.

So I have two arrays

```
title_id: [1542, 1507, 47, 1436, 1527, 3, 173, 1534, 1876, 398]
ref_no: [10, 10, 74, 12, 9, 35, 10, 9, 1, 42]
```

I would like to query such that the index of the first array should be AND with the index of the second array.
Like if: title_id = 1542, I want to AND it with ref_no = 10 only. and so on.

I tried the following query, but it is like multiplying the indecies:

```
Book.where("title_id IN (?) AND ref_no IN (?) ", @ids.map(&:title_id), @ids.map(&:ref_no))
```

using: RoR 3, PGSQL

Comment: You want `(title_id = 1542 and ref_no = 10) or (title_id = 1507 and ref_no = 10) or (title_id = 47 and ref_no = 74) or ...`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is pretty easy in PostgreSQL's flavor of SQL. You could JOIN to a VALUES expression like this:

```
select books.*
from books b
join (values (1542, 10), (1507, 10), ...) as dt(t, r)
     on b.title_id = dt.t and b.ref_no = dt.r
```

Or you could use ANY and an array or IN:

```
where (title_id, ref_no) = any (array[(1542,10), (1507, 10), ...])

where (title_id, ref_no) in ((1542,10), (1507, 10), ...)
```

Or the usual big mess of ORs:

```
where (title_id = 1542 and ref_no = 10)
   or (title_id = 1507 and ref_no = 10)
   or ...
```

The second option (IN variant):

```
where (title_id, ref_no) in ((1542,10), (1507, 10), ...)
```

is the clearest match to your intent IMO. I can't think of any pleasant way to get AR to build that but, since we're dealing with integers and don't have to worry about quoting and escaping issues, we can do it with a bit of string wrangling:

```
trs = @ids.map { |o| "(#{o.title_id.to_i}, #{o.ref_no.to_i})" }.join(',')
Book.where("(title_id, ref_no) in (#{trs})")
```

You could probably construct the OR version with some long chain of incomprehensible AREL calls but I tend to give up on AR and go straight to SQL when things get more complicated than the baby-talk `a = b and c = d` SQL that AR wants to speak.